# Lambda in Apply

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have 10 columns and I would like to divide each column with the the previous column using apply and lambda. This is my code

```
df.apply(lambda x: df.iloc[:,x+1]/df.iloc[:,x])
```

But got the error message

```
positional indexers are out-of-bounds
```

I tried to use this

```
df.apply(lambda x: df.iloc[:,x+1]/df.iloc[:,x] if x < df.shape[1] else np.nan, axis = 1, result_type='expand')
```

But gives different error messages

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: welcome to SO, read following notice for you : [mre]

Answer (score 1):

You lambda receives the full Series, not the column position, also even if you have numbers as names you will generate a non existing position for the last `x`.

You would have needed to use something like:

```
df.iloc[:,1:].apply(lambda x: x/df.iloc[:,x.name-1])
```

But, much better use vectorial code with [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
df.div(df.shift(axis=1), axis=0)
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
out = df.div(df.shift(axis=1), axis=0)
```

Output:

```
    0     1    2
0 NaN  2.00  1.5
1 NaN  1.25  1.2
```